# How to set an event on the parent element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

help me figure out how to set an event on the parent element (`<tr>`)
I can't find the error in the condition

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('table tbody tr').each(function(){
     $(this).find('a:first').click(function(){
        if($(this).parents().get(1).tagName == 'TR') {
         $(this).parents().get(1).find('tr').css('background', 'red'); //What's wrong?
        }
});
</script>

<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><a href="#">text</a></td>
         <td>text</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, the formatting, I don't see any more special tag

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log` or `alert($(this).parents().get(1))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey you are missing closing **`});`**  for `each` statement. Here is the correct version of your code

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function(){
     $(this).find('a:first').click(function(){

           if($(this).parents().get(1).tagName == 'TR') {
               $($(this).parents().get(1)).css("background-color", 'red'); //What's wrong?
           }
      });       
 });
```

***[Working Example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/QSrDW/1/)***

**EDIT:**  you can shorten above code very easily like assigning a class to anchor tag.

```
<a class="bindclick" href="#"></a>

$(".bindclick").bind("click", function(){
   var parent = $(this).parents("tr").get(0);
            OR
   var parent = $(this).closest("tr"); // http://api.jquery.com/closest/
   $(parent).css("background-color","red");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.find('a:first').click(function(){
         $this.css('background', 'red');
     });
});
```

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WGdyk/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table tr a:first").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").css('background', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This works:

```
$(function() {
  $('tr a:first').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('tr:first').css({background:'red'});
  });
});
```

Comment: yes, this will work, the problem is that, [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) bubble up to the root. meaning, if this table are nested, all it's parents TR of `a:first` will be affected.

Comment: +1 I agree with reigel. you need to add .get(0) after parents("tr") and wrap it as jQuery selector like `$($(this).parents('tr').get(0)).css...`

Comment: Nested tables? o.O Then just use parents('tr:first')

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure about this, but I think that when you call $(this) inside the second function for clicking the a tag, $(this) is the a tag itself, and not the $(this) which is in the outer function the tr element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function(){
          var $this = $(this);
          $this.find('a:first').click(function(){
             $this.css('background', 'red');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function(){
     $(this).find('a:first').click(function(){
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
     });
});
```

easy one.